# Alternative for setInterval() in a jQuery photo slider

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I am creating a photoslider in JQuery from scratch and I am using setInterval() in order to make the images run every 3 seconds. However, I am using a play/stop button and it doesn't respond as I wanted since it has to wait for the interval to finish in order to detect the button. Is there another option I can use so the play/stop buttons responds immediately? Thanks!

```
var test = parseInt($interval.val(),10)+1000;
var test2 = test; 
function runInterval() {
    $(".slider #" + count_image).show("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    }, 500);
    test2 = test;
    if ($("#parrafo").text() == "Play") {
        $(".slider #" + count_image).delay($interval.val()).hide("slide", {
            direction: "left"
        }, 500);
        if (count_image == max_images) count_image = 1;
        else count_image = count_image + 1;
    }
    $interval = $("select#mySelect option:selected");
    test = parseInt($interval.val(), 10) + 1000;
    clearInterval(s);
    s = setInterval(runInterval, test2);
}
s = setInterval(runInterval, test2);
```

Comment: Sounds like the interval and your slideshow code are too coupled. When the button is clicked, can you not set a variable that says it's been clicked, and then the photoslider won't do anything, even when the callback is fired.

Comment: that's the interval function: 
function runInterval()
{                
     $(".slider #"+count_image).show("slide,{direction:"right"},500);test2 = test;

 if($("#parrafo").text() == "Play" )
 {
   $(".slider #"+count_image).delay($interval.val()).hide("slide",{direction:"left"},500);

   if(count_image == max_images)
    count_image = 1;          
   else
    count_image = count_image + 1;  
 }
 $interval = $("select#mySelect option:selected");
 test = parseInt($interval.val(),10) + 1000;
 clearInterval(s);    
 s = setInterval(runInterval, test2);
} s = setInterval(runInterval,test2);

Comment: Can you paste code in the original question please? And use something like http://jsbeautifier.org/ to format if possible.

Comment: sure! I am sorry for the lack of format (this is the first time I post a question here)

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yMXep/8/). I *think* it works like you want it to. I'm using `div`s instead of `img`s, which shouldn't make much difference.

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div id="0" class="img">0</div>
    <div id="1" class="img hidden">1</div>
    <div id="2" class="img hidden">2</div>
    <div id="3" class="img hidden">3</div>
    <div id="4" class="img hidden">4</div>
</div>
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>200</option>
    <option>1000</option>
    <option>2000</option>
    <option>3000</option>
</select>
<button id="parrafo">Start/Stop</button>
<span id="status"></span>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.slider, .img {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
.img {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

JS:

```
var slideshowActive = false;
var slideshowTimeoutDuration = 5000;
var slideshowTimeout = -1;
var currentImg = 0;
var numImgs = 5;
var slideDuration = 500;

function showImg(img) {
    $(".slider #" + img).show("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    }, slideDuration);
}

function hideImg(img) {
    $(".slider #" + img).hide("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, slideDuration);
}

function swapImgs(currentImg) {
    hideImg(currentImg);

    var nextImg = currentImg + 1;
    if (nextImg >= numImgs) {
        nextImg = 0;
    }

    // Show the next image after the currentImg has been hidden (after slideDuration).
    setTimeout(function () {
        showImg(nextImg);
    }, slideDuration);

    return nextImg;
}

function onSlideshowTimeout() {
    console.log("onSlideshowTimeout", new Date());

    if (!slideshowActive) {
        $("#status").html("Slideshow aborted");
        return;
    }

    currentImg = swapImgs(currentImg);

    if (slideshowActive) {
        // Continue the slideshow if active, by setting a new timeout.
        slideshowTimeout = setTimeout(onSlideshowTimeout, slideshowTimeoutDuration);
    }
}

$("#parrafo").click(function () {
    // Toggle the slideshow active.
    slideshowActive = !slideshowActive;

    // If the slideshow is now active, start it.
    if (slideshowActive) {
        // Only calculate the duration when the Start button is clicked.
        var $interval = $("select#mySelect option:selected");
        slideshowTimeoutDuration = parseInt($interval.val(), 10) + 1000;
        // Start the slideshow.
        $("#status").html("Slideshow started with duration=" + slideshowTimeoutDuration + "ms");
        slideshowTimeout = setTimeout(onSlideshowTimeout, slideshowTimeoutDuration);
    } else {
        $("#status").html("Slideshow stopped");
    }
});
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot Paul! That's exactly what I wanted! And thanks for commenting it as well!

Comment: I forgot to mention, as it uses `setTimeout` and not `setInterval`, there is no need to cancel the timeout (with a `clearTimeout`). Instead we only repeatedly set the timeouts if the slideshow is active.